# What is callback interface?

Tags: apex, system

In Salesforce there is an interface `StubProvider` which is a callback interface. Could anyone explain what is callback interface and how it is different from the normal interface?

Comment: A simple google search got me this [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_StubProvider.htm)

Comment: a useful apex implementation that exploits this (based on Mockito) is [ApexMocks - on GitHub](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know all information that you gave but I need some description of callback interface.